# STM32F4 ADC Multimode with Master being triggered by timer

Tags: stm32, adc, stm32cubeide

First of all: I'm using the CubeIDE toolchain offered by STM.

Some of the STM32 microcontrollers have multiple ADCs (for example STM32F446xx) and offer a multi-regular-simultanuous mode (DualMode or even TripleMode), where the ADC1 is set as a master and triggers the other ADCs, which are in slave configuration.

When I use this configuration in the CubeIDE I can still set the trigger for the ADC1 to a timer, and not use it in continuous mode. Does this configuration make any sense? I could also just set the trigger for all the ADCs I want to be synchronized on the same timer, no?
So the way I understand it, multimode only makes sense, when I want to have it running in continuous conversion mode and have all the ADCs be synchronized.

Comment: You may want to post this to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've posted a similar question, but with more detail in electronics. If I get good answers there, I will ask this question there as well. I've seen a lot of similar questions like mine in this community, so I was assuming it might fit in here.

Comment: Alright. I think the point of having an interrupt trigger multiple ADCs is to sample different signals with one single trigger rather than having an interrupt (timer or external or whatever) for each ADC. You could do it like this or individually, bottom line is it depends on what you're trying to do, you can figure whatever works for you best and use that strategy.